# Elasticsearch completion suggester skip_duplicates non duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch

I am confused with the `skip_duplicates` Elasticsearch completion suggester. The settings and mappings is like this:

```
        {
            "settings":{
                "index" :{
                    "analysis": {
                        "analyzer": {
                            "autocomplete_analyzer": {
                                "type": "custom",
                                "tokenizer": "standard",
                                "filter": [
                                    "lowercase",
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "mappings":
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "category": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "category_suggest": {
                            "type": "completion",
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

I have docs like this.

```
              "category_suggest": {
                "input": [
                  "Automotive",
                  "Auto",
                ]
              }
```

and also have docs like this

```
              "category_suggest": {
                "input": [
                  "Automotive",
                  "Car",
                ]
              }
```

If I use _search endpoint, submit this query, with `skip_duplicates=true`.

```
    "suggest":
        {
            "suggestions":{
                "prefix": "Aut",
                "completion":{
                    "field": "category_suggest",
                    "size": 5,
                    "skip_duplicates": true
                }
            }
        }
```

It only returns

```
  "suggest": {
    "suggestions": [
      {
        "text": "Aut",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 3,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "Auto",
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "oCNRa4IAiXc1hBrN9UnM",
            "_score": 1.0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I set `skip_duplicates=False`, both 'Auto' and 'Automotive' will be returned. Is that because in one of document, `category_suggest` field has both 'Auto' and 'Automotive'. I am using ES 7.10 python.

Thanks

Comment: I found your example strange, the documents despite having a suggestion the same as the others are different (array input) so skip_duplicate would not remove a suggestion since the document arrays are different. It would work if you had two documents with "input": ["Automotive","Car"]. With your data I was not able to simulate this reported problem.

Comment: @rabbitbr Thanks for helping. I update my question with settings and mappings. Maybe it helps you to reproduce the results. And I do not fully understand what you said. To make my example more clear to you. I have two examples, 1) has input "input": [ "Automotive","Auto"], 2) has "input": ["Automotive", "Car" ]. I though it should output both "Auto" and "Automotive" as suggestions but it only gives me "Auto" even though I set the "size = 5"

Comment: Have you managed to resolve it? I still haven't had the same results as you. [Here](https://gist.github.com/andreluiz1987/3704f2c6d28ea11caccad1e789c9e25b) is my code.